# How to edit attribute using XPath in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath

I want to use XPath to search for a `task_status` while looking for a uuid.

Here is my `XML` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test1>
<typ>task</typ>
  <datestamp>20150602153306</datestamp>
  <datecreate>20150602153306</datecreate>
<task uuid="92F7F685-C370-4E55-9026-020E3CDCEDE0" status="0">
    <task_headline>TEST2000</task_headline>
    <task_subject>There is a Problem.</task_subject>
    <task_action>Solve it!</task_action>
    <task_priority color="#E62C29">high</task_priority>
    <task_status>200</task_status>
    <task_note></task_note>
</task>
<task uuid="AWFWF-C510-4E52-9026-020E3BFDDSG" status="0">
    <task_headline>TEST3000</task_headline>
    <task_subject>Another Problem</task_subject>
    <task_action>Solve it again.</task_action>
    <task_priority color="#E62C29">high</task_priority>
    <task_status>200</task_status>
</task>
</Test1>
```

What I want is: search for `uuid=AWFWF-C510-4E52-9026-020E3BFDDSG` and set status = 1000.
Both of them are attributes

```
    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
                        XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
                        String xpathexpression = "//task[@uuid=\"" + taskItems.get(position).get(task_uuid) + "]";
XPathExpression expression = xPath.compile(xpathexpression);
                        NodeList nl = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Isn't that right? 
I get the uuid from a `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`.
Maybe I do an mistake in the expression while adding the uuid from `taskItems`.

After I solved the Problem, how can I change the status to 1000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed the closing double quotes here :

```
String xpathexpression = "//task[@uuid=\"" + taskItems.get(position).get(task_uuid) + "\"]";
```

It may be slightly more readable if you use single quotes instead :

```
String xpathexpression = "//task[@uuid='" + taskItems.get(position).get(task_uuid) + "']";
```

Comment: YES!!! Thats it!! Thank you you helped me! :) Can you tell me how I can change the status from 0 to 1000?

Comment: @korunos I'm not java programmer, can't tell you how from top of my head (but I believe it should be very straightforward).